# Why do we have "in" keyword in Comparator

Tags: kotlin, generics

This is kotlin code for implementation of binarySearch method:

```
public fun <T> List<T>.binarySearch(element: T, comparator: Comparator<in T>, fromIndex: Int = 0, toIndex: Int = size): Int {
rangeCheck(size, fromIndex, toIndex)

var low = fromIndex
var high = toIndex - 1

while (low <= high) {
    val mid = (low + high).ushr(1) // safe from overflows
    val midVal = get(mid)
    val cmp = comparator.compare(midVal, element)

    if (cmp < 0)
        low = mid + 1
    else if (cmp > 0)
        high = mid - 1
    else
        return mid // key found
}
return -(low + 1)  // key not found
}
```

Why do we have type of Comparator as  and not just T?

Do we use in for just readability purposes? Or is there an actual use in the above code snippet where if we don't use "in", things will not work?

Answer (score 1):

The use of Comparator instead of Comparator allows the method to accept a Comparator that operates on a supertype of T.

This is useful because it allows the binarySearch method to be more flexible and handle cases where the elements in the list are subtypes of the type of the search element. For example, if T is Animal and the list contains Dog and Cat objects, the method could still work with a Comparator that operates on Animal objects, even though the search element is a Dog or a Cat.

If we use Comparator, the binarySearch method would only accept a Comparator that operates on T objects specifically, which would limit its flexibility.

So, in this case, the in keyword is used for more than just readability purposes, and it ensures that the method can accept a Comparator that operates on supertypes of T.

Comment: I tried to copy down the binarySearch implementation here goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#w4l03e88v6ivbl5lf671m and removed the <in T> from comparator. I you see in the main function, although the list is of type Orange, binarySearchs is still accepting the fruitNameComparator. So why do we need to specify in keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It theoretically allows it to be more flexible. Example:

```
interface Fruit {
    val englishName: String
}

val fruitNameComparator: Comparator<Fruit> = compareBy { it.englishName }

class Apple: Fruit {
    override val englishName = "Apple"
} 

class Orange: Fruit {
    override val englishName = "Orange"
}

fun main() {
    val orangesList: List<Orange> = listOf(Orange(), Orange())
    val searchResult = orangesList.binarySearch<Orange>(Orange(), fruitNameComparator)
```

This works because a `Comparator<Fruit>` is a subtype of `Comparator<in Orange>`, but it would not be a subtype of `Comparator<Orange>`.

However, the usefulness in this example is very limited, you could have called:

```
orangesList.binarySearch<Fruit>(Orange(), fruitNameComparator)
```

or omitted the generic type completely to allow it to be inferred, and it would work fine, because your `List<Orange>` is also a `List<Fruit>`.

If the binary search function returned the actual item found, so it was returning `T`, then the extra flexibility would be more useful, because the `T` could be resolved to `Orange` instead of `Fruit`, so the returned item will be the more specific type.

Comment: I tried to copy down the binarySearch implementation here goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#w4l03e88v6ivbl5lf671m and removed the <in T> from comparator. I you see in the main function, although the list is of type Orange, binarySearchs is still accepting the fruitNameComparator. So why do we need to specify in keyword.

Comment: Oh, you're right. What's happening when you do that is your `List<Orange>` gets upcast to `List<Fruit>` to make the function a match. I'll have to give it more thought whether `in T` buys you anything here.

Comment: The only way I can make it fail without the `in T` is if I specify the type, such as calling `binarySearch<Orange>(...`. It may be that was left in out of habit/clarity. If your function was returning `T` instead of an `Int`, you would want to use `in T` so you get an Orange back, instead of an Orange that has been upcast to the less specific Fruit type.

Comment: `If your function was returning T instead of an Int, you would want to use in T.` I don't think this is true. If my function is returning T, then I would definitely want to use out T as it is what covariance is.

Comment: @Hack123 That doesn't make sense. Function types cannot be covariant or contravariant. They can only be covariant or contravariant in the sense that they could be bounded within some other type.Here's an example to illustrate what I'm saying: https://pl.kotl.in/mYaLKYRjU

Comment: So regarding your previous comment, when you say that the code written in kotlin is just for clarity and is not required as such?
Also, I might be confused, in the code snippet I shared, if we are writing Comparator<in T> doesn't it mean that all the methods inside Comparator are going to consume T and not provide any output in T. What does it have to do with the return type of my function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252672/discussion-between-hack123-and-tenfour04).

Comment: (1) In this example where `T` isn't returned, it only helps with allowing specifying type at the usage site `binarySearch<Orange>(...`. Not very useful since we usually omit the function call type when we can. (2) When you call a function like this without specifying what `T` is, the compiler infers what `T` is, and it will try to infer the most specific type possible to keep your code as flexible as possible. Without `in T`, it can only infer that `T` is a `Fruit`, not an `Orange`. So if the function returns `T`, it will return Fruit instead of the more specific and helpful Orange type.